# Put commas into variable numbers

Tags: php, number-formatting

Is it possible to put commas into numbers from a variable? Like

```
echo "Gold: ",$stats['gold'];
```

That might display **135345634**, but I'd want it to display **135,345,634**

If there's a way to do this automatically for every number that'd be amazing!

Comment: @wavemode's answer is correct and you should figure out what to do based on his answer. I still showed you how to do it in my answer though, in case you are still stuck.

Comment: @nem it is not correct for my specific situation

Comment: well then check out my answer, i think its what you are looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**`number_format`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function to do that:

```
$number = YOUR_NUMBER;
$result = number_format($number);
echo $number; // prints your number as comma separated
```

This function has many more capabilities so check out the link above.

If you are displaying currency, you can also use [**`money_format`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function

For your case, answer could be:

```
$result = number_format($stats['gold']);
echo "Gold: ".$result;
```

As far as this part:

> If there's a way to do this automatically for every number that'd be amazing!

Here is one way of doing that:

```
foreach($stats as $key => $value) {
    $result = number_format($value);
    echo $key.": ".$result."\n";
}
```

[**`Short sample run`**](http://ideone.com/I3L4XQ)

Answer (score 4):

The PHP function [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) does what you need:

```
$num = 135345634;
$str = number_format($num);
echo $str; // "135,345,634"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I dont have a " set number", it depends on what the variable is, can be 1, 100 or 100000 :3